# If I have two keys in redis like X:Y and X:Z can I get both of them by searching on X?

Tags: redis

Is there a way to search by a parent part of the key in Redis?

For example:  `X:Y = [1,2] and X:Z = [4,6]`

Both keys have a key subpart of X.

Can I run some sort of operation to get `X = [1,2,4,6]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redis has no built-in ability to do that, but you can use it to build it.

Yes, you can search for keys in Redis according to their name, but it would be inefficient in terms of performance. Refer to [`SCAN`](https://redis.io/commands/scan) for more information.

A more performant way is to index your keys, so searching is done in sub-linear time. Refer to [Secondary Indexing with Redis](https://redis.io/topics/indexes) for some pointers.

Once you've retrieved the names of your keys, it appears that you want the union of their values. One candidate data type that supports this functionality is the Redis Set via the [`SUNION` command](https://redis.io/commands/sunion).

An alternative approach entirely to scanning/indexing, sets and unions is to use a single data type for all the "keys" sharing the same prefix ("X"). The Redis Hash can do that for you, and while it doesn't offer the equivalent of the union operation on its fields, it can be implemented by a Lua script (or even the application).

Other than these two approached, I'm confident that there are more ways to use Redis to achieve what you're trying to do. Choosing the right one is a matter of understanding all the requirements, but I'm afraid that information is lacking from the question.

Comment: Wow thank you for the really great answer. I'm still a redis noob but the more I learn about Redis the more I see how great it is.

Comment: My pleasure - happy hacking :)